# iPhone SDK - presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated no video but audio

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

I'm trying to show a MPMoviePlayerViewController.

```
MPMoviePlayerViewController* theMoviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]
                              initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:media_url]];
```

If I'm adding theMoviePlayer View to the current view via addSubview , everything is fine. But if I'm trying to show the player in a modal window, only the audio of the video is played back in the background. The view is not beeing displayed.

```
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:theMoviePlayer];
```

Answer (score 0):

I guessed you called presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated in viewDidLoad and your view controller was not added to a navigation stack.

[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated] will present MPMoviePlayerViewController as modal view and you can only present modal view controllers from controllers that have already been shown onscreen.

So to fix it you can either <1> push your view controller into a navigation stack and call [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated] after viewDidLoad

<2> Without a navigation stack you need to call [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated] in the next run loop after viewDidLoad, e.g. with a **IBAction** or using **dispatch_after**